# Why IVsSolution can convert to IVsHierarchy type

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
var solution = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
var hierarchy = solution as IVsHierarchy;
```

I read the MSDN about IVsSolution and IVsHierarchy, but the documents do not mention that a solution can be casted as an IVsHierarchy, why?

Comment: MSDN mention Passed to GetService(Type) to return a reference to IVsSolution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.svssolution?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: the point is IVsHierarchy, solution can be casted as an IVsHierarchy,and hierarychy not be null.But they are not exist inheritrelationship